# .bashrc file adds a couple of tens of spaces to the prompt

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, bashrc

I got myself a .bashrc file off the net. I checked it beforehand, didn't detect anything bad about it.

One thing that's odd about it, is that several spaces are added to the terminal command line.

Screenshot:

[image]
Those spaces are not put there by me.

The file can be found here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html

Comment: well, show us your $PROMPT

Comment: @akira: unbound variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the prompt contains non-printing characters, they must be surrounded by `\[…\]`. Otherwise bash counts these characters as part of the width of the prompt.

The prompt settings are missing several instances of `\[…\]`. Here are the ones I've found after a cursory glance:

```
function fastprompt()
{
    unset PROMPT_COMMAND
    case $TERM in
        *term | rxvt )
            PS1="\[${HILIT}\][\h]\[$NC\] \W > \[\033]0;\${TERM} [\u@\h] \w\007\]" ;;
        linux )
            PS1="\[${HILIT}\][\h]\[$NC\] \W > " ;;
        *)
            PS1="[\h] \W > " ;;
    esac
}

function powerprompt()
{

    PROMPT_COMMAND=_powerprompt
    case $TERM in
        *term | rxvt  )
            PS1="\[${HILIT}\][\A - \$LOAD]\[$NC\]\n[\u@\h \#] \W > \
                 \[\033]0;\${TERM} [\u@\h] \w\007\]" ;;
        linux )
            PS1="\[${HILIT}\][\A - \$LOAD]\[$NC\]\n[\u@\h \#] \W > " ;;
        * )
            PS1="[\A - \$LOAD]\n[\u@\h \#] \W > " ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the function `powerprompt`.

If you have copied and pasted it into your `.bashrc`, you may have gotten spaces at the beginning of the lines ending with `\` (backslash).

(Can you post your real `.bashrc` somewhere instead)?
Or try: `echo \"$PS1\"`

(**EDIT:** Of course I mean "at the beginning of the lines *following* the lines ending with `\`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the code that is in the

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Shell Prompt
#-------------------------------------------------------------
```

section of the `.bashrc` file.  This looks to be the area that controls the appearance of the prompt.

What does your prompt look like now?  If you don't notice a change, make sure you start a new Terminal window.

Beyond the `.bashrc` file in your home directory, there are system-wide configurations in the `/etc/` folder.  They are usually found in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash_profile` (note they are not hidden, no prepended `.`) depending on the flavour of Linux your are using.

Also - do you have any other `.bash_profile` or `.profile` like files in your home directory which might also be acting to configure the prompt?